# how to store multiple lists into one list in ftl(freemarker template)

Tags: list, freemarker

I have 5 lists of product Ids. each list has some products coming from database tables. I have used EntityQuery for fetching data from tables.

```
<#assign Productid1 = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("ProductId1").from("PurchaseOrder").queryList()>
<#assign Productid2 = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("ProductId2").from("PurchaseOrder").queryList()> 
<#assign Productid3 = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("ProductId3").from("PurchaseOrder").queryList()>
<#assign Productid4 = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("ProductId4").from("PurchaseOrder").queryList()>
<#assign Productid5 = EntityQuery.use(delegator).select("ProductId5").from("PurchaseOrder").queryList()>
```

I want to store all the products from 5 lists into one list without changing the type. the type of one list in which all products will be there will be of type sequence.
how shall I achieve this in FTL?

The values in  each list will be like this

```
pid000001 pid0000050 pid0000013 pid0000019 pid0000025 pid000003 pid0000034 pid0000039 pid0000043 pid0000047
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add items to a list by assigning to the same variable using the `+=` operator. For example:

```
<#assign myList = ['A','B']>
<#assign myList += ['C','D']>

<#list myList as item>
${item}
</#list>
```

This will output:

```
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: but this will change the type of myList from sequence to string. I don't want the type to be changed.

Comment: Adding to a list / sequence will not change the type.